# Java server client (I/O connectionException)

Tags: java

I have written a program where the client should be able to establish connection, and write to som message to the server. And the server should print this message.

The problem is that once the client connect to the server, I get an exception with the following message:

```
java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
at Client.<init>(Client.java:21)
at Server.startServer(Server.java:42)
at Server.main(Server.java:62)
```

My code for the server is as shown below:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server {

    private int port = 5555;

    public void printServerAddress() {
        InetAddress i = null;
        String host = null;

        try {
            i = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        host = i.getHostAddress();

        System.out.println("Contact this server at address: " + host + " and port: " + port);
    }

    public void startServer() {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        Socket socket = null;
        String fromClient = null;

        try {

            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

            while(true) {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                if(socket != null) {
                    System.out.println("Connection from: " + socket);
                }

                Thread thread = new Thread(new Client(socket));
                thread.start();

                while((fromClient = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("From client: " + fromClient);
                }

                reader.close();
                socket.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server();
        server.printServerAddress();

        server.startServer();
    }

}
```

And the code for the client is:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Client implements Runnable{

    private int port;
    private String serverAddress;
    private PrintWriter writer;
    private BufferedReader reader; 

    public Client(Socket socket)
    {
        try {

            socket = new Socket(serverAddress, port);
            writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Write message to server:");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(scanner.next() != "quit") {
            writeToServer(scanner.next());
        }
        writer.close();
    }

    public void writeToServer(String message) {
        writer.write(message);
    }

    public void readFromServer() {
        String msg = null;

        try {
            while((msg = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("From server: " + msg);
            }

            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 5555);
        new Client(s);
    }
}
```

Any idea on what I did wrong, and how to fix my problem?

Comment: When you start the server, can you telnet to it? For exemple, use `telnet XXX 5555` where XXX is the server address. Once connected, the anyting followed by a return on the telnet and the server should receive it...

Comment: Yes I can telnet to the server, and the server seems to work as expected. So I guess my error is in the client implementation. As hawks pointed out, this must be cus the serverAddress is null, and port is 0.

Answer (score 3):

```
socket = new Socket(serverAddress, port);
```

serverAddress is null and port is 0.
try to define the serverAddress variable and the port before call `new Socket(serverAddress, port)`

or change

socket = new Socket(serverAddress, port);

to

this.socket = socket;

## edit

you can change your constructer to :

```
public Client(String serverAddress, int port)
{
    try {

        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress, port);
        writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: How could I pass the serverAddress and port so that they are not null and 0? I guess I could let the constructer for Client take not only a Socket as parameter, but also serverAddress and port. But isn't this an ugly solution? I'm thinking some experienced programmers maybe could point out/hint a smarter way? 


If I do this.socket = socket, I will have to have a field of a socket, but I will never use this field, since I don't use socket else where than in the constructor

Comment: You can just read the socket passed in the constructer. Or you can create the socket object if your constructer is like this Client(String serverAddress, int port){ Socket socket = Socket(serverAddress, port); ...}